# software updater stuck on applying changes

Tags: updates, 13.04, beta

I'm on 13.04 and I'm downloading the update to beta but its stuck on applying changes. The other night i left it on all night came back and it was still on applying changes. What can I do now? Right now it's still on applying changes

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue when upgrading to 13.04. It crashed. 
What worked for me was to reboot and complete the upgrade using synaptic. Everything seems to be in order now (although I plan to do a fresh install when the final 13.04 gets out at the end of the month).
Best,